# Remove HandyCafe start-up (home) page from Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, homepage

After uninstalling HandyCafe software, it's start-up page `http://search.handycafe.com/` still remains active in Firefox.

No matter what you change your start-up page to, next run of Firefox changes back to `http://search.handycafe.com/`

No related software found in Control Panel - Programs

No related plug-ins are installed in Firefox.

No related executables are found in Windows start-up

How do I remove it? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first answer wasn't what you were looking for, I did a simple Internet search which found this on the Mozilla Support Forum.

[unable to change "Handycafe" homepage](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/783341).

Comment: Thanks. user.js in profile directory of firefox was overriding homepage settings. Much better job... =)))

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be a well know issue on several sites. Here is a page with some fairly detailed instructions how to remove the software and the browser redirecting vulnerability.

[How To Remove The Search Handy Cafe AtesSoft Virus (Handycafe.com Scam)](http://botcrawl.com/how-to-remove-the-search-handy-cafe-atessoft-virus/)

Comment: Yes, I checked this one already. No valuable information there. Remove, Repair, Uninstall. Steps which any user will perform by default. And it's NOT a virus. =)))

Comment: You might want to state that information in your question. There is not way any of us can know what you've done unless you tell us.

Comment: In my question I already specified placed I went through, same places are posted in your link. You did very basic Googling and posted first matching link here. Lousy job + unreasonable criticism.